# Calling specific methods on a Solana Solidity program

Tags: solidity, solana, solana-web3js

I've built a simple smart contract to run on the Ethereum blockchain and I'm trying to replicate some of it's behavior on Solana. After making some slight changes I've managed to compile the program with [Solang](https://solang.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) targeting Solana, but I'm not sure how to go about calling the methods; there doesn't seem to be a great wealth of documentation or examples on this. For example, if my program were written as follows:

```
contract Example {
  function foo(...) { ... }
  function bar(...) { ... }
}
```

How would I specify a call to `foo` vs a call to `bar`? Furthermore, how would I encode the arguments for these method calls?

Currently my approach is to use the [@solana/buffer-layout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@solana/buffer-layout) library to encode my arguments as a struct, starting with `lo.u8('instruction')` to specify the method call (in the example case, I assume `0` would refer to `foo` and `1` would refer to `bar`). I've taken this approach based on looking at the source code for [@solana/spl-token](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@solana/spl-token) (specifically [this file](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token-swap/js/src/index.ts) and it's dependencies) but I'm not sure if it will work for a program compiled using [Solang](https://solang.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and the buffer layout encoding has been throwing an unexpected error as well:

`TypeError: Blob.encode requires (length 32) Uint8Array as src`

The code throwing this error is as follows:

```js
const method = lo.struct([
  lo.u8('instruction'),
  lo.seq(
    lo.blob(32),
    lo.greedy(lo.blob(32).span),
    'publicKeys',
  ),
])

const data = Buffer.alloc(64); // Using method.span here results in an error, as method.span == -1
method.encode(
  {
    instruction: 0,
    publicKeys: [firstPublicKey, secondPublicKey],
  },
  data,
);
```

While this type error seems obvious, it doesn't line up with the sample code in the [solana-labs/solana-program-library](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token-swap/js/src/index.ts) repository. I'm pretty sure this problem has to do with my use of `lo.seq()` but I'm not sure what the problem is.

Is my approach to this correct besides this type error, or is my approach fundamentally wrong? How can I call the intended method with encoded arguments? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a better library for you to use, `@solana/solidity`, which has a `Contract` class to encapsulate calls on the contract.

For example, in your case, you could do:

```
const { Connection, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, Keypair } = require('@solana/web3.js');
const { Contract, Program } = require('@solana/solidity');
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');

const EXAMPLE_ABI = JSON.parse(readFileSync('./example.abi', 'utf8'));
const PROGRAM_SO = readFileSync('./example.so');

(async function () {
    console.log('Connecting to your local Solana node ...');
    const connection = new Connection('http://localhost:8899', 'confirmed');

    const payer = Keypair.generate();

    console.log('Airdropping SOL to a new wallet ...');
    const signature = await connection.requestAirdrop(payer.publicKey, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);
    await connection.confirmTransaction(signature, 'confirmed');

    const program = Keypair.generate();
    const storage = Keypair.generate();

    const contract = new Contract(connection, program.publicKey, storage.publicKey, EXAMPLE_ABI, payer);

    await contract.load(program, PROGRAM_SO);

    console.log('Program deployment finished, deploying the example contract ...');

    await contract.deploy('example', [true], program, storage);

    const res = await contract.functions.foo();
    console.log('foo: ' + res.result);

    const res2 = await contract.functions.bar();
    console.log('bar: ' + res2.result);
})();
```

Example adapted from https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/solang#build-for-solana

More information about the package at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@solana/solidity

Comment: The Contract constructor takes a signer for the final argument (`payer` in your example), but I'm getting the user's wallet through Phantom wallet which does not provide the secret key. What can I pass here as the signer/payer?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's an API which allows for signing transactions, but as an alternative, you could have the client fund a temporary keypair, use that in the contract, and finally refund the user's wallet at the end.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this code. How can I use the Contract from @solana/solidity for already deployed contract. I have the JSon and so file, I also know the program id. I want to call the functions without deploying every time. How can I construct the already deployed contract in Solana? Many thanks in advance..

Comment: solidity link 404